# assoc array with multiple select lists php html

Tags: php, html, associative-array

```
array (size=1)
  'FIXDATES' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2015-01-01' (length=10)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2015-02-13' (length=10)
```

I am attempting to populate two drop down menus with associative data like that above. I would like the key to populate drop down one, and the corresponding date values to populate the list below based on the first list. I can get the first one working fine, but can't seem to get the second. Is what I am trying to do even possible?

```
 <td><select name="division" id="division">
   " <?php
       $divisionList = getDivisionList();
          foreach ($divisionList as $field) {
          print '<option>'.$field. '</option>';
          } ?> "
 </select></td>
```

EDIT:

expected output would be 2 select lists, list a populated with key values and list b populated with values associated with the key. my attempt at this is below, and as you can see it does not work:

```
<th><label for ="division">Division</label></th>
<td><select name="division" id="division">
" <?php
 $divisionList = getDivisionList();
   foreach ($divisionList as $key => $value) {
   print '<option>'.$key. '</option>
 <th><label for ="date">Date</label></th>
  <td><select name="date" id="date">'
   .print '<option>'.$value.'</option>';
} ?> " </select></td>
```

Comment: What is the structure of $divisionList? What you need is possible using array_keys() and array_value(), but not enough info to answer now.

Comment: @slbteam08 the structure is as my first example, string keys with an array of dates per key.

Comment: Can you show some sample what kind of output you are expecting ?

Comment: @AlankarMore see edits

Comment: You can use two loops on same data ....one to show the keys and other to list the values

Comment: Can you show us the expected RESULT you want in html? based the example you given. It¨'s hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Might this is the output you are expecting. If Yes then check the below code:
[image: Output Assumed on basis of your comment]

Check the code for the same:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>
<label for ="division">Division</label>
</th>
<th>
    <label for ="date">Date</label>
</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>
<select name="division" id="division">
<?php foreach($array as $key => $data) {
 echo "<option>".$key."</option>";
} ?>
</select></td><td><select name="division" id="division">
<?php foreach($array as $key => $data) {
  foreach($data as $key1 => $date) {
     echo "<option>".$date[0]."</option>";
    }
} ?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

`$array` = is your sample array you have shown in question.

Comment: using your method i'm definitely the closest i've been ... however using this example for array: $array = array("test"=> array("2015-01-01","2016-01-01"), "test1" => array("2016-01-01")); all dates are populated for both test and test1 vs just the relevant ones per date. I'm guessing i'm gonna have to figure out the ajax route....

Comment: Oh now for this you have to use ajax and on change event of first select box you have to show the dates. Or if it is the static data I mean the dates are not so much you can create multiple select boxes and hide show them depends on the selection in second first box